# why MinMaxScaler's fit_transform function drop some customer_ids on the dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn

The goal of the code below is to scale all columns (except `customer_id`) inside `df_filtered` to 0-1 range and save the output to `df_scaled`, while preserving all `customer_id`.

```
# Separate customer_id column and feature columns
customer_ids = df_filtered['customer_id']
features = df_filtered.drop('customer_id', axis=1)

# Transform the feature columns
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(features)

# Create a new DataFrame with the scaled features and customer_id column
df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaled_features, columns=features.columns)
df_scaled['customer_id'] = customer_ids

# Reorder the columns (optional, to match the original DataFrame)
df_scaled = df_scaled[['customer_id', 'trx_cnt', 'gtv', 'service_cnt', 'active_day_cnt', 'recency']]
```

However, I noticed ~10% of `customer_id` inside `df_scaled` becomes NaN, hence I'm losing the identifier. The row numbers persist but the value of `customer_id` becomes NaN.

Why is this happening and is this expected?

If not, could you point out the way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your data looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think df_filtered includes its own index.
That is why `df_scaled['customer_id'] = customer_id` is not working correctly.

Try this code instead.

```
df_filtered = df_filtered.set_index('customer_id')
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df_filtered),
                         columns=df_filtered.columns,
                         index = df_filtered.index)

df_scaled = df_scaled.reset_index() # remove this line if you want to customer_id be used as index
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you elaborate more on the reason? Would like to understand this so I can avoid this in the future

Comment: customer_ids has index of df_filtered, but df_scaled may have different index as it is generated by df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(scaled_features, columns=features.columns). That is why df_scaled['customer_id'] = customer_ids is not working properly. 
Another suggestion is to convert customer_ids into ndarray so that it has not index. For instance, df_scaled['customer_id'] = customer_ids.values will also be work